# How to add data and update in arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have data to my list and I save it. That's working properly but when I add data again to list it deletes old data. But I don't want that. I want it to add next to the already existing data or append to existing list.

```
List.add(new Users("name", "surname"));
adapter = new Adapterr(this,List);
saveData();
```

Respective methods are as follows:

```
private void saveData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(gonderilenFallar);
    editor.putString("adapterss", json);
    editor.apply();
}



 private void loadData(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
    getActivity().getSharedPreferences("shared preferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("adapterss",null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Adapterr>>(){}.getType();
    List = gson.fromJson(json,type);

    if(List == null){
    List = new ArrayList<>();
                   }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append the data to already existing data you need to

- Fetch the list if already exists
- Append data to that list

  ```
  private void saveData() {

  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
  Gson gson = new Gson();

  //Fetch List
  String json = sharedPreferences.getString("adapterss",null);
  Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Adapterr>>(){}.getType();
  List<type> list = gson.fromJson(json,type);

  //If already exists append to that list
  if(list != null && list.size() > 0){
      for (int i = 0; i < newListToBeAppended.size(); i++) {
          list.add(newListToBeAppended.get(i));
      }
  } else{
      //If not exists add the list which is fresh
      list = newListToBeAppended;
  }

  String listJSON = gson.toJson(list);//Assuming gonderilenFallar is your list
  editor.putString("adapterss", listJSON);
  editor.apply();
  }
  ```